# Embed an SVG in an SVG

Tags: inkscape

How do I embed (link file) one svg in another?

If it's not obvious, then I'd like to keep it vectorized (when saving as pdf from inkscape) rather than rasterized (using <image>).

---

Duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71654338/embed-an-svg-in-an-svg

Comment: One shouldn't cross-post between stacks. Pick the stack you feel you'll get the best answer and stick with that. If a question meed migrating, Mods will do that.

Comment: I dont think this is a question of how you do it is svg itself. Every svg renderer will handle this differently. Its an implementation detail. But rather how inkscape behaves.

Comment: @joojaa, okay, forget about svg. Encapsulating and including an external file is a basic capability. How do I do that in inkscape?

Comment: @ZoharLevi and what makes you think inkscape has this basic capability.

Comment: Don't cross-post questions please. We'e removed the copy on Stack Overflow.